# What happens if more than one cosmetic with footprint spells is equipped?

Tags: team-fortress-2

If I have multiple footprint spells equipped, what happens? Do both happen together, or does one take priority?

I did some tests, but I want to make sure the results were not just me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, footprint spells don't stack.**

[Source](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Headless_Horseshoes_(halloween_spell))

The page also mentions that the cosmetic in the 'misc' slot takes priority, which I suspect means the bottom cosmetic slot. I have a feeling that the article was originally written back when there was a dedicated hat and misc slot.

Comment: Damn, I was hoping to be able to make some cool combinations.